# Why am I consistently getting the wrong answer in differentiation with fractional powers?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I'm working through the PSET in this [video](https://mathswebsite.com/a-level/edexcel/core-1/differentiation/v/differentiate-more-complex-powers) for Core-1 Mathematics:

I understand how to differentiate, but when it comes to converting the fractions or roots to powers, I'm getting everything wrong.
Is there a prerequisite I'm weak on? 
What should I do?

Comment: Please give some examples. How are you trying to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should know these rules:

- $\sqrt[q]{x^p} = x^{\tfrac{p}{q}}$.
- $\dfrac{1}{x^p} = x^{-p}$.

For example $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}} = \dfrac{1}{x^{\tfrac23}}=x^{-\tfrac23}$. This has now the form that you can differentiate.